# How to get provider of user in django which registered with django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

**I am going to get provider of user in django**
I tried to loop through queryset `user.socialaccount_set` but got only username of user.
Is there are any solution to get provider?

Comment: user.socialaccount_set.all()

Answer (score -1):

```
  social_accounts = SocialAccount.objects.all()
        for account in social_accounts.all():
            account.provider
```

Comment: NameError: name 'SocialAccount' is not defined

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on how to provide quality answers. It's useful to provide context and details on why this might be an ideal solution.